# Simple question on matrix partition notation

Tags: matrices, notation

I have a simple question regarding notation of submatrices within a matrix. Consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and a matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{l \times n}$. Now, if I want to gather $A$ and $B$ in a matrix $C$ such that

$C=\begin{bmatrix}
    A \\
    B
\end{bmatrix}$,

then would

$C=\begin{bmatrix}
    A & B
\end{bmatrix}^T$ or $C=\begin{bmatrix}
    A^T & B^T
\end{bmatrix}^T$

be proper notation? I guess the question if whether to consider $A$ and $B$ merely as symbols or as the matrices with the actual numerical entries.

Sorry if this is a stupid question - I tried finding something on this, but without any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$C^T=[A^T~~B^T]$$
This is the required transpose.